# Is there a limit to the number of WiFi networks that Ubuntu/NMCLI can see?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, network-manager, nmcli

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and trying to find information on its ability to see larger numbers of available WiFi networks.

I have personally successfully tested up to 32 simultaneously-visible WiFi networks.

Is there a limit to the number of available networks Ubuntu can see at any one time?  If so, what is that limit, and what happens if Ubuntu encounters an environment where that number of networks are visible?

For context - think about a system running 14.04 in a large convention center hall, where there can easily be well over 50 WiFi networks visible at once.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify the objective?  Except for, of course, knowing the number?  In other words, if all the available networks were not available, I don't think it would actually hurt the device or crash the OS.  The only results is that any networks outside the visibility buffer just wouldn't be displayed.

Comment: That is the objective - to find out whether there is a limit to the number of WiFi networks Ubuntu can **see** at a given moment.

If there is not a limit, that is fine - I'm just trying to determine the effects of my system being in an environment where there are perhaps 100 available wireless networks at a given time.

Comment: I'm saying, from a technical standpoint, there would be no effect on your system.  There used to be a time when hackers would overflow buffers so that they could crash applications and execute code during the crash event.  But currently programmers by design as well as the bug fixes in the various languages, there is error handling for such events.  If the buffer reached it limit you would only see the output of the buffer.  The device would continue to operate as normal.

Comment: That's great - thank you very much for the answer.  Just what I was looking for.